# Convert array of objects to object to objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a function that returns me an array of objects. How do I manipulate the data to return me an object of objects?

Below is my example:

```js
const includedStates = ['NJ', 'NY'];

const withoutMap = () => {
  return {
    "NJ": {
      fill: "red",
      clickHandler: (event) => console.log('Custom handler for NJ', event.target.dataset.name)
    },
    "NY": {
      fill: "red",
      clickHandler: (event) => console.log('Custom handler for NY', event.target.dataset.name)
    }
  };
};

const withMap = () => {
  return includedStates.map(item => {
    return {
      [item]: 'red',
      clickHandler: (event) => console.log(event.target.dataset.name)
    }
  })
};

console.log('withoutMap =>', withoutMap());
console.log('withMap =>', withMap())
```

Please advice. I want the withMap function to return me the datastructure of how withoutMap returns.

The datastructure I expect is

```
{
  "NJ": {
    "fill": "red",
    "clickHandler": (event) => console.log('Custom handler for NJ', event.target.dataset.name)
  },
  "NY": {
    "fill": "red",
    "clickHandler": (event) => console.log('Custom handler for NY', event.target.dataset.name)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and construct an object as you're iterating:

```js
const includedStates = ['NJ', 'NY'];

const withoutMap = () => {
  return {
    "NJ": {
      fill: "red",
      clickHandler: (event) => console.log('Custom handler for NJ', event.target.dataset.name)
    },
    "NY": {
      fill: "red",
      clickHandler: (event) => console.log('Custom handler for NY', event.target.dataset.name)
    }
  };
};

const withMap = () => {
  const result = {}
  includedStates.forEach(item => {
    result[item] = {
      [item]: 'red',
      clickHandler: (event) => console.log(event.target.dataset.name)
    }
  })
  
  return result;
};

console.log('withoutMap =>', withoutMap());
console.log('withMap =>', withMap())
```

Another option is to use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const includedStates = ['NJ', 'NY'];

const withoutMap = () => {
  return {
    "NJ": {
      fill: "red",
      clickHandler: (event) => console.log('Custom handler for NJ', event.target.dataset.name)
    },
    "NY": {
      fill: "red",
      clickHandler: (event) => console.log('Custom handler for NY', event.target.dataset.name)
    }
  };
};

const withMap = () => {
  return includedStates.reduce((result, item) => {
    result[item] = {
      [item]: 'red',
      clickHandler: (event) => console.log(event.target.dataset.name)
    }
    return result;
  }, {})
};

console.log('withoutMap =>', withoutMap());
console.log('withMap =>', withMap())
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will just map the elements in the array itself, you should use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce it to an object.

```js
const includedStates = ['NJ', 'NY'];


const withReduce = () => {
  return includedStates.reduce((result, item) => {
    result[item] = {
      fill: 'red',
      clickHandler: (event) => console.log(event.target.dataset.name)
    };
    return result;
  },{});
};

console.log('withReduce =>', withReduce())
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `reduce()` with dynamic property names and destructuring:

```js
const includedStates = ['NJ', 'NY'];

const withMap = () => includedStates.reduce((result, item) => ({
    ...result,
    [item]: {
      fill: 'red',
      clickHandler: (event) => console.log(event.target.dataset.name)
    }
  }), {});

console.log('withMap =>', withMap());
```